# Azure Mobile Service with iOS client - how to insert a record when the app is closed

Tags: ios, mobile, azure, service

I have an iOS application that inserts records to an Azure Mobile Service database periodically. When the application becomes inactive (i.e. when my app delegate's applicationWillResignActive method is called) I would like to insert a record to tell my AMS application that the client session has ended.

When I try to insert a record from either applicationWillResignActive or applicationDidEnterBackground the completion block is never reached. To keep the app delegate method from returning before the AMS insert completes, I've tried calling usleep to delay 100ms in a loop while checking for a flag that I set in the insert completion block.

I suspect that a run loop or operation queue needed by the AMS client library isn't being serviced when I'm in this state, but the AMS client library docs don't have enough detail to tell if that's the case.

This seems like a pretty common scenario - has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Do you start the upload on the main thread or a background thread?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain that making a network request from applicationWillResignActive is frowned upon by iOS.  This method is used to clean things up, not make use of additional resources.  You can however request that iOS keeps your app running in the background for some period of time.  You should be able to do something like this:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskID = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

    //Perform call to mobile service
    myservice.dosomething(Completion:^{
        //Call to mobile service is done
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:taskID];
    });

}];
```

That should enable you to make the call and then get the response back.  Remember though that iOS can still kill your app before this completes if it chooses to.